# How to get Gnome 3.14 on UbuntuGnome 14.04LTS

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I just read that GNOME has been updated to version 3.14 (http://www.gnome.org/news/2014/09/gnome-3-14-released/) and I was wondering if there was a way to update the current release of UbuntuGnome 14.04.1 LTS to that new version of GNOME?

Comment: To TRY gnome 3.14 you can download the live image or build it yourself. http://www.gnome.org/getting-gnome/

Comment: The question is not how to try it but how to integrate it into a running system.

Comment: Also: http://askubuntu.com/q/536721/178596

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNOME 3.14 was released yesterday, I think. Even [Rico](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ubuntu/testing?field.series_filter=trusty) won't have it by now. Build from source if you must have it now, or wait for Rico's PPA to be updated.