# How to get Gnome 3.14 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome

Is there a way to get ubuntu gnome 3.14 on ubuntu 14.04 ??

Thank you in advance

Comment: Same issue here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/528239/how-to-get-gnome-3-14-on-ubuntugnome-14-04lts

Comment: I believe that question is not answered, So I am asking other people to help me with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3.12 is still in development, and 3.14 will is still very much in development as well. For instance, currently for Debian it 83/77% ready.

Gnome 3.14 is available for 14.*10 (utopic)* the [Gnome Staging](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging) PPA (only Gnome 3.12 is available for 14.04), which is updated fairly regularly with staging releases of the. You can use the PPA with a few others as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452864/how-to-get-gnome-shell-3-12-on-ubuntu-14-04). You could use the utopic PPA, but that would likely cause issues (on Trusty - installing Utopic [when it is released](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) may make it easier).

You can also get a image of Gnome from [here](http://www.gnome.org/getting-gnome/) - this however is based on a Fedora release *(Fedora 21, which includes it anyway (and works great :)*, not Ubuntu. You could get 14.10 (which it also [nearly ready](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseSchedule)), and use the gnome-staging PPA.

Also:

- http://www.webupd8.org/2014/09/gnome-314-released-see-whats-new.html
- https://wiki.gnome.org/ThreePointThirteen
- http://worldofgnome.org/early-preview-shell-3-14-on-ubuntu-gnome-14-10/

---

### Edit

You can now get 3.14 in Utopic 14.10, as explained [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/how-to-install-gnome-314-in-ubuntu.html):

> GNOME 3.14 was released back in September and it includes some
>   interesting changes like multi-touch gestures for both the system and
>   applications, re-worked default theme, new animations as well as
>   various enhancements for the code GNOME applications. More information
>   HERE.
>
> Unfortunately, Ubuntu GNOME 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn) ships with GNOME
>   3.12 for the most part (there are even some GNOME 3.10 packages, like Gedit or Nautilus) but, as usual, you can install the latest GNOME
>   (3.14) by using a PPA.
>
> Unlike previous versions, installing GNOME 3.14 from the GNOME 3
>   Staging PPA in Ubuntu 14.10 doesn't break Unity however, there are
>   things that don't work as they should, like:
>
> - very large icons for some apps in Unity Dash and other places - screenshot;
> - the default Ubuntu theme (Ambiance) doesn't work properly with some applications (screenshot) and Adwaita doesn't support Unity's CSS
>     window decorations so you'll have to use a theme that supports GTK
>     3.14 and Unity, like Zukitwo, but even then you may encounter various issues like up/down arrows for indicators (screenshot);
> - Nautilus, Totem and Gedit use client-side decorations and the default GNOME menu, so they will look out of place in Unity.
>
> **And that's just on a first look so there might be many other issues. That's why I don't recommend using this PPA if you're using Unity!**
>
> **As usual, the latest GNOME is available in the GNOME 3 Staging PPA and it's not considered ready for general use (you will encounter
>   bugs!), so make sure you read the PPA description before using it.
>   Follow the instructions below on your own risk and only if you know
>   how to fix your system in case something goes wrong!**
>
> There are two more things I should mention, so you'll know what to
>   expect:
>
> - on my laptop running Ubuntu 14.10, applications that use client-side decorations have a large shadow at the bottom
>     ([screenshot](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Vd53Lr2AUpM/VE-3YMblAnI/AAAAAAAAUuc/gAYTb41g1BM/s1600/gnome314-shadow-bug.png)).
>     This didn't occur in the two virtual machines I've tested the GNOME
>     3.14 installation under Ubuntu 14.10, but you may encounter this bug, and I didn't find out what's causing it;
> - CSD applications have minimize and maximize buttons for some reason, even though GNOME doesn't use this by default - you can
>     disable them via *GNOME Tweak Tool* > *Windows* > *Titlebar Buttons*.
>
> ### Install GNOME 3.14 in Ubuntu GNOME 14.10
>
> **Warning:** Please read the output before entering 'Y' for the "dist-upgrade" command below to make sure important packages won't be
>   removed and if the "dist-upgrade" command tries to remove important
>   pages, abort the installation and remove the PPA! Also, it's a good
>   idea to save the list of packages upgraded by using the instructions
>   below, in case you want to revert the changes and ppa-purge fails.
>
> Currently, only the GNOME 3 Staging PPA is required to upgrade to
>   GNOME 3.14 in Ubuntu 14.10 however, some packages might be moved to
>   the GNOME 3 PPA later on and that might break things if you didn't
>   enable this PPA on your system, that's why by following the
>   instructions below, you'll add both the GNOME 3 PPA and the GNOME 3
>   Staging PPA.
>
> That said, let's proceed
>
> 1. Install GNOME 3.14
>
>    To add the GNOME 3 and GNOME 3 Staging PPAs and upgrade to GNOME 3.14 in Ubuntu GNOME 14.10, use the following commands:
>
>    ```
>    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
>    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
>    sudo apt-get update
>    sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
>    ```
>
>    During the GNOME 3.14 upgrade (or purge) process, you may encounter an issue similar to this:
>
>    ```
>    (gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0:29077): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory
>    ```
>
>    If that happens, firstly install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:
>
>    ```
>     sudo apt-get install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
>    ```
>
>    And then fix this issue by running the following commands:
>
>    - 32bit:
>
>      ```
>      sudo -i
>      gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache
>      exit
>      ```
>    - 64bit:
>
>      ```
>      sudo -i
>      gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache
>      exit
>      ```
> 2. Reboot (a simple logout / login may not be enough so to avoid any issues, reboot your system).
> 3. (Optional) Install GNOME 3 applications not available by default in Ubuntu GNOME 14.10.
>
>    You may also want to install the GNOME 3 apps which are not available by default in Ubuntu GNOME 14.10 (Polari, Bijiben, Clocks,
>      Sound Recorder, etc.) - install them using the command below:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install polari gnome-sound-recorder bijiben gnome-clocks gnome-music gnome-photos gnome-boxes
>    ```
>
>    *(Epiphany is still at version 3.12.0)*
>
> ### How to revert the changes
>
> If for whatever reason you want to revert the changes made by adding
>   the GNOME 3 and GNOME 3 Staging PPAs, you can purge them (purging a
>   PPA downgrades all the packages from that PPA to the version available
>   in the official Ubuntu repositories and disables the PPA) using
>   ppa-purge:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
> sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
> sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
> ```

---

### Edit:

If you really want have a go at adding 3.14 to 14.04, you could manually add/edit the PPAs for 14.10 to your sources list:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu utopic main'
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu utopic main'
sudo apt-get update
```

**WARNING**: This will likely fail due to dependices, and if not might break stuff. You will probably want to backup any important data first in case. Using 14.10 (or Fedora) would be simpler.

Comment: The original question is about Gnome 3.14 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, not 14.10.  Is it really that impossible to have the packages backported to 14.04?  Yes, unity may break, etc., but if a user doesn't have unity isn't it possible to get some LTS love around here?

Comment: @rik.shaw You could try adding the PPA for 14.10 to 14.04 - but likely something won't or will break. See edit

Comment: @rik.shaw: I'd like it too, but it's a non-trivial amount of work, even simply to backport for those of us who use Ubuntu GNOME: there are dependencies on updated versions of system components that are relied on widely outside GNOME.