# How to upgrade to GNOME 3.30 on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome

I am a new Linux user and I heard about the new **GNOME 3.30**. Can someone help me with the steps to upgrade my GNOME?

I have GNOME 3.28, **Kernel 4.18.7**

**Note:** I don't wish to upgrade to 18.10

Comment: At the moment, Gnome 3.30 is unavailable for 18.04, and it is unlikely to change, given its LTS status.

Comment: You have `Kernel 4.18.7`. Most users of 18.04 have `4.15`. I suggest you'd be better off with a rolling release distro so that you get the latest available versions. Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't cater to such needs.

Comment: Ohh!

Yeah, I did a manual upgrade because i read that the latest kernel has many fixes.

Thanks for the information.

Regards!

Comment: Update 11/27/18: Ubuntu devs are working on 3.30 https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/nautilus-3-30-status/8907 . It's not forgotten. There is NO commitment to backport 3.30 to earlier releases of Ubuntu.

Comment: Correct, he writes: "...you will be able to get all of that work from this PPA14, which is available for disco only." 18.04 users will have to stay with the slow laggy gnome < 3.30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [The Best New Features in GNOME 3.30](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/09/gnome-3-30-features)
:

> It will be available to download as source code [from the GNOME Gitlab page](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME), and be available to try via a live USB image.
>
> Although many Linux distributions come with GNOME by default few distribute major new releases right away, instead choosing to ship the update as part of a new release.
>
> Rolling release distros are the exception of course, so Arch, Manjaro and others will likely make this update available soon.

Please note the second paragraph.

There's also a detailed answer to an earlier question of similar nature here: [How to get Gnome 3.14 on ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/536729/248158).

Edit: and now GNOME 3.30 is [available via Flatpak](https://news.softpedia.com/news/gnome-3-30-desktop-environment-is-now-available-on-flathub-as-flatpak-runtimes-522993.shtml).

Edit on 20181121: I couldn't find it in https://flathub.org/apps/category/All

Comment: Emmm,

Ok, then I just need to wait.

Thanks for you reply!

Comment: Arch is actually already on 3.30 :)

Comment: Arch is Arch :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've been trying to install Gnome 3.30 via flathub website as per the suggestion of the article but it's nowhere to be found. Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't see it at https://flathub.org/apps/category/All as well. Maybe they yanked it? Anyway, I'll edit my answer. Thanks! If you know how to partition your system, you could install Ubuntu 18.10 separately. That'll give you 3.30 optimized for Ubuntu at least for the life of 18.10 (nine months from the date of release).